# Can ActiveMQ queue consuming retry process, able to check any state changes of the original message in the queue

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using a ActiveMQ queue and consuming it via Camel + JMS Transaction. On a system failure, activate the retry process using "DeadLetterChannel" as bellow.

```
<camel:errorHandler id="deadLetterErrorHandler" type="DeadLetterChannel" deadLetterUri="activemq:ActiveMQ.DLQ">
    <!-- delayPattern = 5s;1m;5m;1h;5h;10h;20h = 36h -->
    <camel:redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="7" delayPattern="1:5000;2:60000;3:300000;4:3600000;5:18000000;6:36000000;7:72000000" />
</camel:errorHandler>
```

While testing I investigated, the retry process do not consider the original message status (eg: original message is removed due to incident) on the queue. Even broker get down, retry process is continuing.

In general original message will not change, but it MAY be changed due to special cases. In such cases, can I able to check original message status (like availability) and stop the retry process? Are there any direct option to do that?

I refer few documentation but I could not found a solution.

Comment: Can you explain what you consider by "original message status"?

Comment: Original message means the message in the queue which is retrying. Status change means, eg: removing the message (which is retrying) from the queue.